# Maven BasicDataSource Errors on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

We recently started converting a large webapp to Maven, and everything seemed to be working great, but no matter what we do, Maven doesn't recognize the tomcat-dbcp.jar file on the tomcat server.  In my dependencies, I have set the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.26</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I get the following stacktrace:

```
Error:  javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z
URI:    /as/CheckReport
Error Message:  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z
Status code:    500

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:913)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:226)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:302)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2208)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2191)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1945)

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1412)

com.networkfleet.sre.common.db.Resource.getDBConnectionDEV(Resource.java:75)

com.networkfleet.sre.app.checkreport.CheckReportSrv.doGet(CheckReportSrv.java:63)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)

org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)

org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)

org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)

org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)

org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)

org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)

org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2463)

org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2452)

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I should point out that this was never a problem before Maven, and we haven't made server side changes that should cause this.

I'm currently using a odjbc7.jar driver, which is up to date and has been installed through Maven, appears in my repository in the correct location, and is included in the app itself via a system scope.  This is the identical driver file that is being used in the non-maven build, where this error does not appear.

Comment: Please include the entire stacktrace, like the actual cause.

Comment: (And what do you mean by "Maven doesn't recognize the tomcat DBCP jar"?)

Comment: I will, give me one moment.  And I mean Maven doesn't use the classes in it, it doesn't see them.

Comment: I added the whole stack trace.

Comment: Maven is no longer involved at the time your program is running. So far it looks like a version mismatch between what's expected and what you have; I'd do a very careful comparison between the libraries in the two builds.

Comment: Except for those downloaded by maven as dependencies for other libraries, they're factually the same.  I reference them from the same library file as I did my non-maven build.  I understand that maven isn't running at run time, it's only there to build the project, but the project isn't being built correctly now because of Maven, and I don't know where I made a mistake that is causing it to act in such a manner.

Comment: "Except for those downloaded by Maven..." ... That's the point-you need to check all your dependencies in both projects against each other.

Comment: What jdk version did you use for non-maven build? And did you specify java version in your maven compiler plugin?

Comment: 1.7, and yes I did.  It's specified to use 1.7.